# User admin status isn't being remembered (admin area disappears after a while)

Tags: php, cookies

I'm new with PHP and decided to play around with cookies on my site. I added cookies to my login system which keeps the user logged in for 1 year after they log in. This works fine.

However, I don't know how to make the cookies remember which users are set to admin status in the database. There is a bug so the admins who are logged in aren't able to view the admin area after a while even though they are still logged in. Any ideas what this could be?

Login Code:

```
$password=md5($_REQUEST['PASSWORD']);
        $UserName=mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['USERNAME']);
                 $hour = TIME() + 60*60*24*30;
                setcookie("USERNAME_COOKIE", $UserName, $hour);
                setcookie("PASSWORD_COOKIE", $password, $hour); 

    $query = $mario->DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `" . DBNAME . "`.`users` WHERE `username` = '" . addslashes($_REQUEST['username']) . "' && `password` = '" . md5($_REQUEST['password']) . "'");
    if($mario->DB->NumRows($query) > 0) {
        // Success we have a user!
        $results = $mario->DB->Fetch($query);
        $_SESSION['accountLoggedIn'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $results['userID'];

        setcookie("marioruns_loggedin", true, time()+3600*24*364,"/" );  /* expire in 1 year */
        setcookie("marioruns_username", $results['username'], time()+3600*24*364,"/" );  /* expire in 1 year */
        setcookie("marioruns_userID", $results['userID'], time()+3600*24*364,"/" );  /* expire in 1 year */
```

Config Code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["marioruns_loggedin"]))$_SESSION['accountLoggedIn'] = true;

if(isset($_COOKIE["marioruns_username"]))$_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE["marioruns_username"];

if(isset($_COOKIE["marioruns_userID"]))$_SESSION['userID'] = $_COOKIE["marioruns_userID"];
```

Session_start(); is included
Admin status isn't being stored anywhere in the code, just called from the database when the user loads the profile page (where the admin area is)

Edit:

I have a feeling it could be something to do with the code that displays the admin area on the profile page, this line of code:

```
<?php if(($_SESSION['isStaff']) || ($_SESSION['isAdmin'])) {?>
--- Admin Area Code ---
```

Maybe the session has expired? Not sure.

Comment: Where are you storing the user's role? (aka. how does the system know they're an admin?)

Comment: BTW don't use md5 it's insecure, use SHA

Comment: *...better yet,* use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: As above, plus dont store sensitive data (like password hashes) in cookies. Ever.